# Carregar conteudo dinâmico na navbar

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um *select* na *navbar* com as cidades cadastradas no banco. Para isso estou usando *ajax* para fazer o carregamento delas.

Mas queria uma solução sem precisar usar *ajax*, mas também sem precisar montar a *query* em cada método que aponta para a *view*. Teria como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, não precisa utilizar *AJAX* para isso. O *Laravel* tem uma função chamda `view composer`, onde é possível fazer exatamente o que você precisa.

Vou dar um breve resumo dos dois arquivos necessários e deixar o link para a documentação, onde você poderá consultar a sintaxe correta.

Primeiro você tem que criar dentro do diretório `app/Http`, o arquivo que conterá o código que será exibido na view. Aconselho a criar uma pasta para ficar mais organizado.

```
$cidades = Cidades::get();
$view->with('cidades', $cidades);
```

Depois você precisa criar um arquivo dentro de `app/Providers`, que será o responsável por chamar o arquivo criado anteriormente.

```
view()->composer(
    ['nome-view-navbar'], 'App\Http\nome-pasta-criada\nome-arquivo-cidades'
);
```

Aqui está o link para a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Como você não especificou a versão do seu projeto, coloquei o link para a última.

Comment: Mano era isso mesmo. Obrigado. Vou substituir todos os ajax por ele!